# attempt to index global 'ENT' (a nil value) Removing entity after a certain amount of time

Tags: lua

How would i remove the entity after a certain amount of time.

```lua
local meta = FindMetaTable( "Entity" )

function meta:Kill()
  timer.Simple(5, function() ENT:Destruct() ENT:Remove() end)
end
```

Expected to remove entity after timer but ended up with an error:

```
attempt to index global 'ENT' (a nil value)
```

Comment: How is it that we are supposed to help you? As it is, we have to guess as to what larger game/program/application this poorly formatted code comes from. Please provide more context, and see SO recommendations on posting questions and code snippets. Finally, Lua is telling you that in the current scope `ENT` doesn’t exist. So, what is ENT, where is it declared, etc.? You can’t just throw some new line of code in somewhere and expect it to work without understanding the larger code context.

Comment: The game is garrysmod sorry forgot to add the tag

Answer (score 1):

`ENT:Destruct()` is syntactic sugar for `ENT.Destruct(ENT)`

`.` is the indexing operator.

As `ENT` is a `nil` value you are not allowed to index it. Attempting to do so results in the observed error message.

To fix that you have to find out why `ENT` is nil where you expect it not to be `nil`.

There are various reasons. You assigned a nil value to it. You never assigned a value to it. You misspelled the variable name...

There is no Destruct function in the Garry's Mod documentation btw.